# Asking if the following post could be suitable for the main site Physics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I've cross-posted yesterday this on Meta of the site MathOverflow [*Asking if the following post could be suitable for the main site MathOverflow*](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4597/asking-if-the-following-post-could-be-suitable-for-the-main-site-mathoverflow).

I would like to ask if the following questions can be potentially interesting for the main site. The problem is that I've asked a similar question in past months (with an account now deleted) on the main site Physics Stack Exchange and was not well received (if I remember well I included some discursive, unnecessary or specualtive paragraphs, thus I accept the situation).

> **Question.** I would like to know if some of the following post (see below the title, body with the respective *Question* and some tags) can be suitable for the main site Physics Stack Exchange. **Many thanks.**

My belief is that the following can be interesting, if you can/want pleas add your feedback in commments or as an answer for this Meta Physics Stack Exchange if it is possible, about if my question can be suitable and be on topic for the main site Physics Stack Exchange. If you can to mention some improvement for the future question that I bring here (below, the post) feel free to comment it: I can rewrite/remove some pararaph or choice the more suitable tags, or other improvements with the goal to ask a good question.

If there are no answers or feedback for this post on Meta or if this post isn't useful for this Meta, please let me to know it, that I can to delete this post published on this Meta as soon is possible.

---

### Falsifiability of a hypothesis about a strange phenomena at the edge of Solar System that I postulate

My belief since approximately a year ago is that at the edge/boundary of our Solar System could exist a special region of space-time enjoying the following feature. I add that this is a speculation that didn't  arise from the scientific method, if not through ideas of which I have persuaded myself.

**Hypothesis.** *Each body having certain*$^{*}$ *mass becomes (when this body is placed in this special region that I evoke at the edge of our Solar System) in a micro black hole which evaporates in its corresponding lapse of time.*

*I evoke certain upper and lower limits for such quantity of mass (ordinary matter) for the body placed in this special region (this upper and lower limits are unknown for my person since this is a speculation): let's say that the mass of an apple or a cat, a pendulum or a prism, but also the mass of aircraft carrier, but not the mass of a planetary body, not the mass correponding to a proton.

> **Question.** A) Is falsifiable my hypothesis? I mean that could exist a special region in some place of the space-time, in particular I'm saying in the neighborhood of our Solar System, in such way that bodies with certain masses evaporate since these become in micro black holes when these bodies are placed in such special region. B) What equations, knowledges or instruments/experiments can you propose or evoke  with the purpose to discuss/contradicting claims or facts about the veracity of previous hypothesis? **Many thanks.**

Wikipedia has the article [*Falsifiability.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability)

(black-hole-thermodynamics), (micro-blackholes), (solar-system), (observational-astronomy), (general-relativity), (quantum-mechanics)

Comment: The question that I want **to ask** on the main site is **the second part of the body of the post.** Many thanks again, and feel free to add your feedback. As I said if this post isn't a good idea for this Meta feel free to comment it here (I am connected now and in next hours).

Comment: I emphasize for the persons that casted a downvote that I'm agree in deleting this post. I was asking with good faith/intention this post since I think that the question that I wanted to propose for the main site (the second part of the body of this Meta) should be interesting. I accept the situation, I'm sorry and thanks you very much.

Comment: Many thanks for the users who are upvoting the post. And also many thanks for the attention of the downvoters: I'm adding this comment with sincere words and respect, I know that I'm asking from the ignorance but I think that my hypothesis (second part from the body of this post on Meta) is interesting; in these circumstances I know that many persons can cast a downvote since my beliefs are just beliefs, that aren't science. I accept this, I can't add more if there is no a discussion since my knowledges are poor or if there is no feedback for this our question. Good day all users, and thanks.

Comment: Which is behind of my question, but I didn't express, is my belief as speculation that life on Earth could have glimpsed the holographic principle (I am under the assumption that this principle is according the physical reality of the Cosmos) and tries to exploit this principle in a hypothetical migration process to escape from our Solar System, through its edge, as small singularities (I think that this process, while imaginative, can be a suitable way to travel in an unknown Cosmos, having holes, that shows its fiercest face in the form of radiation and insurmountable distances for Life).

Comment: Of course I tried to modulate the second part of the post don't adding more speculations to avoid to edit a toxic post, but this is which is behind my post. On the other hand in recent days I was seeing video lectures (don't related to my ideas) about amazing physics see the Wikipedia *Quantum biology*. It is really unexpected what physics can be exploited by Life with the purpose to copy and preserve the genetic information of species, in contrast with the state of art of all those famous open problems (that I know just from an informative point of view) in physics.

Comment: And I add with all respect that I think that some examples wich illustrate some theories of modern physics maybe can be interpreted as anthropocentrism, for example the spaghettification of a man (a biological system of matter-energy with information) falling inside a black-hole.

Comment: In recent past days I've seen interesting videos on YouTube, I hope that it is right refer these here (in other case feel free to delete this comment/reference, I add it if some user wants to see these). The videos are from the official channel of YouTube **The Royal Institution**, with titles *An Introduction to Quantum Biology - with Philip Ball* by Philip Ball (February, 18th 2015) and respectively *Jim Al-Khalili - Quantum Life: How Physics Can Revolutionise Biology*, by Jameel Sadik "Jim" Al-Khalili OBE FRS FInstP, see Wikipedia for these honorific/award mentions, (January, 30th 2013).

Comment: Please if some user wants to express in comments the *why* of downvotes it is welcome, I mean if the second part of the body of this post on Meta is suitable for the main site Physics Stack Exchange. That was the question and purpose of the body of this post on Meta. Do you (or your colleagues) know how to solve my **Question** in the second part of the body of the post, the question under the epigraph *Falsifiability of a hypothesis about a strange phenomena at the edge of Solar System that I postulate*?  I'm waiting for your feedback. Many thanks any case for your attention, and a good day.

Comment: I've asked yesterday a post (now deleted) on the site Physics Stack Exchange, and as soon I understood that the question on the body of my post asked yesterday could be a bad question I was deleting it (thanks to the feedback in comments of those users). I believe that my question under the epigraph *Falsifiability of a hypothesis about a strange phenomena at the edge of Solar System that I postulate?* could be a good question, other persons can think in a different way (see the answer of the moderator below). I respect this, I didn't ask on the main site my question. But this is unanswered.

Comment: Columbus "discovered a new world” $\approx$500 years ago. Compare his first travel to America with the video of title *NASA | Satellite Tracks Saharan Dust to Amazon in 3-D* from the official channel of YouTube **NASA Goddard** (February, 25th 2015). You can to evoke what a humble person (who does not know that the Earth's surface is a sphere) would think, if this person was asked to be recruited 500 years ago for a trip to the last country in the East, while the captain wants to sail West. Nobody said that *how things move in the cosmos* must be intuitive. Life exploits only practical things.

Comment: The fact of complexity of Life doesn't seem to me fabulation: it's a suspicion. I do not believe in fabulations, my thread of thoughts is that if Life can use quantum mechanics, from here/this I can not rule out any possibility. There is no doubt that if we could propose/ask to Life to expose its precious genetic information to cosmic radiation, Life would always choose the shortest path. For some reason human species wants to explore other planets (the closest and most prone to life are devastated): we missed an oppotunity to explore the edge of our Solar System with the end of Project Orion

Comment: And that of building an Orion spaceship (I mean the spacraft that refers the Wikipedia with title Project Orion (nuclear propulsion)) in orbit is not fabulation or romanticism, my belief it that we could do it in the past. Are we sure we can do it in the future? I don't know how to estimate if a solar flare event can to have negative consequences for this past project.

Comment: The idea of my post was ask about if my question is suitable for the site, which is decided and I've accept it. With all respect to the persons that are downvoting the post I think that my **Hypothesis** and **Question** in the second part of the body of this post are very interesting and productive, and that it will be very difficult (I think that impossible) to provide a negative answer for my hypothesis. Many thanks in any case for all persons for the attention in this post, and good day.

Comment: Thank you (the users of this community) very much for stop the downvoting of the post. On the other hand if you know some colleague/professor that can be interested in study the question feel free to tell him/her about it. I was thinking about my ideas in previous recent past years. I would doubt that all the ideas behind this post are wrong (I am conviced that is true). I hope that you are well and that this is like a friendly comment and as an invitation for you and your colleagues.

Comment: Thanks to those persons who have voted, and especially casting upvotes this post. It is for me an honor this opportunity to met in this website with very good professional physicists. In recent past days I was asking/adding messages on the chat The $\hbar$ Room about theory or thought experiments about chirality (I mean the Wikipedia *Chirality *) and optical activity of bodies/matter falling into black holes. Many thanks for all users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would not be on topic for this site, since questions asking for review or comments on personal theories are out of our scope.

I'd note that in general, we don't suggest that people pre-post their questions to meta to ask if they would be on topic. What we recommend is that you read about the site's scope in the help center, and if you think your question fits that scope, just ask it. The normal close voting mechanism will determine whether it's treated as on topic or not.

Comment: Many thanks if you prefer delete this your answer that I can delete my post on Meta in next seconds to avoid this situation. I'm accepting delete my post thus. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to delete your post. It doesn't hurt to have an occasional question on meta that asks about whether a question is on topic, we just don't want meta to be dominated by those questions. The reason I mentioned in my answer that this is not the normal procedure is so that other people reading this don't all get the same idea.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention, my intention was only to remove this post on Meta, because maybe was a bad idea to post it here. Many thanks again, and then I accept the situation. Any case feel free to take the decission that you want (or yours colleagues/professors of your moderator team) about my post on Meta, in the future. Good day.

Comment: I think that my hypothesis is falsifiable, any case if this is a non sense it should be easily deduced from physics. This comment is just to draw your attention or the attention of your colleagues (professors that you know, then feel free to tell them my proposal). I hope that this last comment is right and I'm not disturbing to you, I add it with all respect. On the other hand I believe that it could be unexpected what objects or phenomena may happen/have in the Outer Solar System, for example I refer with all respect the preprint on arXiv **2004.14192** by Edward Witten, and reference [4].

Comment: Yesterday I was invited and I was discussing the second part of my post in one of the chat rooms. Many thanks for the generosity and patience of those physicists. On the other hand I add here a reference for a famous engraving, I say the engraving from the article of Wikipedia with title  *Flammarion engraving*. I wish to you and your colleagues a good day. And I am available for more extended discussions.

Comment: I've cross-posted my post on Meta of MathOverflow with title *Asking if the following post could be suitable for the main site MathOverflow*, this [*post*](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4597/asking-if-the-following-post-could-be-suitable-for-the-main-site-mathoverflow) few minutes ago. Many thanks. If my proposal for MathOverflow isn't suitable (a post for the main site MathOverflow) or I delete the Meta of MathOverflow, I think that the right is avoid an unnecessary edit to add it in the Meta of Physics Stack Exchange this information. In other case I should edit our Meta post soon.

Comment: I'm sorry about news that you've edited in your recent post on Meta. Many thanks for your patience, and best wishes. Isn't required a reply of this message.