# Petition about the clousure of my post on Physics Stack Exchange about gravitational geons in our Solar System, to be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen

This is a petition for the attention of moderator team, and the professors of Physics Stack Exchange, about the clousure of my post on Physics Stack Exchange about gravitational geons in our Solar System, to be reopened. If I can I order better this list of reasonings and expand this with other ton of reasons, as for example that you can not to remove the foundations/bedrocks of the Great History of Life, humanity, journeys of of discovery...

> **Question.** I add below some reasonings why you can to reopened [our post edited on Physic s Stack Exchange with identifier **758263**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758263/falsifiability-of-a-hypothesis-related-to-a-gravitational-geon-at-the-edge-of-so) few days ago, please do it. Please reopen my question 758263 on the main site Physics Stack Exchange. **Many thanks.**

-Philosophers don't know what's the nature of truth for a specific story/tale, and physicists, I think don't know what's the nature of reality.

-Our tradition was the exploration of the natural environment and to carry the fire (nuclear propulsion) to unexplored territories, and downvoters seem to reject this fact, in circumstances of need such as those that humanity lives.

-I think that was broken the fundamental rule in technology by Andrew Grove because we have not traveled using nuclear propulsion of spacecrafts  designed by Dyson and other scientists to explore our Solar System. In addition, I don't understand (and I reject this specific application) the application of Gott's copernican principle for the space race. I think that the reality of our Solar System is rare or strange from my point of view.

-In the past there was academic corruption of mathematical physics because there were epicycles in the explanation of nature motion of planets of our Solar System, instead of observations. Your observatories are able to use the technology of gravitational waves, and your knowledges of quantum mechanics and general relativity to elucidate the veracity of our **Hypothesis**, The study of gravitational waves or very distant black holes
it must be postponed until we know what our Solar System is like.

-The astronomic knowledges of many regions of our Solar System seem be describd as hypothetical or conjectural, because you've not enough information about the edge of our Solar System (carries of information that tell it to you). You don't know the initial conditions or the events that occurred in our Solar System in the remote past. To me close my post seems unfair, because you as physicists don't care about these facts.

-While you know that the nature of matter/radiation, quantum mechanics and general relativity of space-time and the fundamental interactions of nature are counterintuitive, were casted downvotes and was closed my post and upvoted the kindly answer of the professor who added the argument of Russell's teapot in our unexplored Solar System. I must emphasize that there are many people who make sports bets daily, and who spend part of their salary, because they believe have a hope of winning (it's a very sad story).

-The size of the instrument that you need to probe the theories that you consider mainstream science could be related to your deficient knowledges of our Solar System: the horizont that seems cenrosed by the Nature. You are insisting in that there was  not a crisis in mathematical physics, but I believe that there was a problem in past with an  article by Hneri Poincaré, in the context of the stability of our Solar System: pure mathematicians arose (this is my testimony, I got 5 downvotes in MathOverflow when I edited my post with just 12 views).

-I believe that Life probed our Solar System, in a similar way that humanity exploited patterns in waves, winds. Please the downvoters who casted votes against my post could to seem refractary to critical thinking or passionate about theories as string theory, wormholes,  supersymmetry, Dyson spheres, alien probes or primordial black holes in our Solar System, Fermi paradox,... Please moderator team of Physics Stack Exchange consider that you must demarcate what considering you by mainstream science: I would like to know if the content of the video with title *Gravitational waves: a new frontier?* , by professor Paul Davies edited yesterday on the official channel of YouTube **The Institute of Art and Ideas**, could be considered by this moderator team as mainstream science.

-It seems that there are physicists who think that they can get a theory of everything of Nature  from their office or laboratory, this seems self-centered, in my opinion. But the important part is that many physicists don't criticize this thought. Physicists don't even hear about problems like the problem of odd perfect numbers, applications of Lucas–Lehmer primality test or what is the Riemann hypothesis, while pure mathematicians like very much that a problem as Riemann hypothesis have hundred of equivalent formulations.

-In this site Physics Stack Exchange there is is freedom for denial of importance of Schrödinger's cat, I can to add the identifier of post. My post is downvoted without a refutation. We need a framework in which we can to elucidate these paradoxes.

-In this kind of forums could be persons who denied that physics is a continuous process of learning from Nature, for example you get first a diagram of kind showed in System of the World from the Wikipedia *Newton's cannonball* that unifies certain phenomena, secondly you draw the diagram that illustrates the *Equivalence principle* (see Wikipedia)... This is the way, and don't trust that from a laboratory or office of an universitity a physicists can to deduce the physics of cosmos. Always there were transfers of mathematics, navigation, astronomy, physics... and  manufacturing artifacts/devices.

-There is a reasoning that I don't trust either, and it is the issue that professors of the past did physics and mathematics, but that seem to be contributions that are not related. For example Hermann Minkowski did work on relativity but also presented his geometry of numbers, as refers Wikipedia. I can't trust the reasoning of the downvoters or the persons who closed my post if I don't know what they think about these issues. Would they, for example, criticize an eminent professor of physics who made, after a honest career as academic, some statement that cannot be verified? I do not think so, because they maybe have fear.

-While, Life is projected upwards, towards the skies with changes of the symmetry of biological organisms. My belief is that Life probed in remote past our Solar System, this incredible Life that began on our Planet Earth, these incredible LUCA and the last eukaryotic common ancestor LECA, or the biofilms. Many physicists may not care about quantum biology, but I am neither a physicist nor a scientist, it does matter to me and it fascinates me. Please, ... scientists try to copy the performances of living organisms, by biomimicry. And living organims are masters of navigation as you can to read in the book by David Barrie *Incredible Journeys*.

-It is worthy to propose new ideas in science, for example Lynn Margulis and her endosymbiont hypothesis. Know the limits of reductionism, to debate ideas concerning the physics of our cosmic habitat, our Solar System, is justified and is interesting for this site. You may be specialized in particle physics or fluid mechanics and maybe you don't want to give my post an opportunity/chance.

-My question is suitable, humans could always travel before discovering new science of navigation. The attitude of being quiet and mute when things in your profession are going wrong is reinforcing the problem. Procrastination can also be a problem, because of your belief that things can get better in a decade or two. In a decade or two, the site Physics Stack Exchange will continue to editing posts related to mentioned theories (string theory, wormholes, M-theory, Dyson spheres, supersymmetry ,...). In a decade or two, the hopes of many students and readers of Physics Stack Exchange will have waned. The decision to cast downvotes as soon a post is edited, or close my post causes erosion and I can't trust the site Physics Stack Exchange. My post 758263 on the main site is answerable, it seems that you want to abandon the study of the Solar System due your preferences of some theories that could not be falsifiable.

-Science fiction adventures have always fascinated and captivated many scientists, but we have only gone with astronauts to the Moon. We can honor all those astronauts who dedicated their lives to space exploration. I am not going to spend my leisure time or my money on science fiction. How can I be sure of your votes if you don't think about science like me?

-It seems ridiculous for me that I've tried, along years, to ask the cited question on MathOverflow and Physics Stack Exchange and I got antagonism instead of a constructive discussion elucidating the veracity of our question. You will not be able to hide your ignorance behind a wall of downvotes, your science is plasticine modelling clay if you've abandoned the methods and reasonings of physicists of past to deduce the truth of our cosmic habitat, our Solar System.

-The clousure of my question seems wrong because it reinforces the modern astrology, in my view, the astrology of zoo hypothesis, alien probes in our Solar System and other, as ancient aliens, UFOs,... Your downvotes and votes to close this question erodes the site Physics Stack Exchange and could to promote the myth, the fear and skepticism in science. In my view erodes the work of astronomers and physicists of past, dirtying their golden helmets.

-Academicism, and dogmatism must also be taken very seriously, if they have contaminated this site. I have the freedom to ask my post on this site Physics Stack Exchange, that is about your science: *if the three fundamental interactions (which you are able to get technologies, and you know an unified theory for those), the the strong and weak interactions and electromagnetism can be vanished in some region of my cosmic habitat: our Solar System*. How ridiculous that you say that this is my speculation (my personal theory), when **it is your own science!** Our Hypothesis is just a case of scientific deductions, an achievement of physics of past decades.

-The birth of the Web had a context, in the same way that my question and explanations. This Stack Exchange network was not designed for the selfishness and whim of a few users, who use their power to silence the scientific truth, scientifc questions are very important as well as the debate. I invited to you with my question to get a view from the top of our Solar System, and your response was a response similar than the Earth is flat. Becasuse for you maps have not importance.

-You abandoned your work of studying our Solar System and energetic phenomena and catastrophes that could have happened, and now you are neither thoughtful nor generous when I'm asking an obvious and scientific question.
You have no right to censor me (I consider that you have lost the perspective of what science is).

-Can't avoid groupthink? I did the petition to the attention for the person(s) who closed my post on the main site with identifier **758263**, please reopen it. I suffered a lot of downvotes defending my right to ask on Physics Stack Exchange.

-The answer, of professor who edited a post as response of my Hypothesis, was sweet as likes a buttered toast with jam, with tea and sugar of course: his argument is neither a complete answer nor a scientific argument. Nothing is proven at that date. **I am a mathematician and** I stated **this Hypothesis to be true.**

...

I've raised the following flag concerning the message of Moderator:

I felt that the Moderator was wrong because this person ignored my suffereing, and this Moderator edited the message in which the "...I wish you luck finding a place that operates by standards... " that seems an invitation for me to leave the site Physics Stack Exchange, and said that my flags are frivolous, which leaves me helpless. This seems  premonitory in the way that this person has denied help/duty as Moderator. I was victim of harassment and now I can't edit more posts on the site.

Comment: I have purged an extended but unproductive comment discussion. @user250478, if someone has engaged with you in a way that breaks our community guidelines, please flag their post and then disengage. The "disengage" part is important.

Comment: You previously asked a [meta question on whether your main question was on topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12909/195139). When you saw that the answer to that was no, why did you then proceed to ask the main question anyway, and then get surprised when it got closed?

Comment: Some additional comments deleted. Please don’t use chains of comments to work around the comment character limit. If your text won’t fit in one comment, consider posting as an answer, as a new question, or on a different website. We also ask our users to write in English.

Answer (score 6):

A comment you put under the question states:

> I have not any rational explanation of my hypothesis, I have not astronomical observations about it, and my knowledges to support my hypothesis are just speculative.

Which makes it definitively a personal theory and thus not mainstream physics.

Comment: Some comments removed. Further completely baseless claims that other users have "dishonest attitudes" or similar personal attacks may result in suspension - our standards for reasonable and polite discourse apply on meta as well as on the main site.